# MySQL string to set and get intersection

Tags: mysql, sql, math, boolean, set

I have a bad-projected database which have a ID sets in text columns like "1,2,5,10". I need to get an intersection of two columns which are set by same way.
I don't like to do it using PHP or another scripting language, I also not like MySQL custom functions. 
Is there any way to get an intersection of two sets given by comma-delimeter strings?

Actually I don't need to have full intersection, I just need to know is there same numbers in two sets. If yes, I need to have "1", if no same number, I need to have "0".

Thank you.

Comment: How many values can be concatenated? Is there a limit?

Comment: @Madhivanan Sure, there is no more than 20 comma-delimeted values.

Comment: You have bad data, but don't like to use typical solutions to such problems... why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use `REGEXP` to do this with a bit of clever replacing.

Think this should do it (disclaimer: haven't tested it extensively):

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       CONCAT('(', REPLACE(col2, ',', '(\\,|$)|'), '(\\,|$))') AS regex,
       col1 REGEXP CONCAT('(', REPLACE(col2, ',', '(\\,|$)|'), '(\\,|$))') AS intersect
FROM tbl
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b86f/3

To explain: This converts `col2` into a regular expression for matching against `col1`. The `(\,|$)` bit matches against either a comma or the end of the string. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

The code from Steve does not work in all cases. 
For e.x it does not work when a number can be found in another number. INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2)
VALUES ('60,61,64,68,73', '14,16,17,18,1');
With a little tweak it can work:

```
SELECT col1,
col2,
CONCAT('((\\,)', REPLACE(col2,',', '(\\,)|(\\,)'), '(\\,))') AS regex,
CONCAT(',',col1,',') REGEXP CONCAT('((\\,)', REPLACE(col2,',', '(\\,)|(\\,)'), '(\\,))') AS intersect
FROM tbl
```