# Searching multiple values in a Comma-Separated MySQL column in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am **fully aware** of [how bad it is to have Delimited Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) in a Table Column, instead of normalizing data into multiple tables.

Although, I do have a table structure designed *years ago*, which *I will re-design soon*.
Simplified, it looks like this:

```
Table: Newsletters
+------------+---------------+
| subject    | mailing_lists |
+------------+---------------+
| A Test     | 1,2           |
| More Tests | 2,3           |
+------------+---------------+
```

You can see it in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4621b0/2), if you prefer to.

Recently, I gave my users the option to write a **delimited list of mailing list ids** *(like 1,3)*, as a feature to select which newsletters to show in a view.
(e.g. Only show newsletters that were sent to lists with id 1 or 3)

So: **A table column with a delimited list of ids, and delimited ids as an input.**

This would obviously be much easier if the tables were normalized.

So, I solved this in PHP, by exploding the input ids and iterating them to create a query like the one in the [fiddle mentioned above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4621b0/2), which looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `newsletters`
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET("1", `mailing_lists`) > 0
     OR FIND_IN_SET("3", `mailing_lists`) > 0
```

This query perfectly fetches the data I want to get, but I can only create it programmatically, since I have to add a new condition for each id in my delimited list.

Question is: **Out of pure curiosity: Is there a way to avoid the loop in PHP, and make a query without splitting the ids in code?**

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317042/mysql-string-to-set-and-get-intersection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the very useful post by `rakeshjain`, I managed to transform my query into this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,
               `mailing_lists` REGEXP REPLACE("1,3", ',', '(\\,|$)|')
                  as haslists
               FROM `newsletters` B) A
  WHERE A.haslists = 1
```

In the above, I assume that "1,3" is the value provided by the user.
Here is the solved fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4621b0/19

Thank you `rakeshjain`!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to avoid the loop. Just normalize your database structure.

Table "Subjects"
subjectID (INT(11), auto_increment)) | subject (varchar(255))

Table "MailingLists"
listID (INT(11), auto_increment) | listName

Table "Subjects2Lists" (many to many)
subjectID (index) | listID (index)

So you can get every single list ID by executing a simple select / join statement.

```
SELECT 
    list.listID, 
    names.listName 
FROM 
    Subject2Lists AS list 
LEFT JOIN 
    MailingLists AS names 
    ON (list.listID = names.listID) 
WHERE 
    subjectID = 1
```

Comment: I already posted this fact on my question, Marcel, but thank you for the effort.

Comment: Hm ... sorry for that. Thought it could be fine for others, to avoid the problem

For your specific problem I 'd create a stored procedure with the ids of the mailing lists as a parameter. So you can iterate through the ids an create a complete statement and execute it.

Comment: True, but I would rather do it in PHP in that case. I will normalize my table structure, though, since I'm planning a big update, but I thought it would be worth a shot to ask this question.